# java.lang.StackOverflowError when creating a list query

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, calendar, jpql

I want to compare two dates in a query - I get the following error

> EJB Exception: : java.lang.StackOverflowError
>        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1603)
>        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1625)
>        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor523.invoke(Unknown Source)
>        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>        at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.invoke(BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.java:110)
>        at weblogic.persistence.TransactionalEntityManagerProxyImpl.invoke(TransactionalEntityManagerProxyImpl.java:79)
>        at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.invoke(BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.java:91)
>        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy218.createQuery(Unknown Source)
>        at model.Services.SessionEJBDossierBean.getDossierFindAllParDepartementDBTECHandUrgen(SessionEJBDossierBean.java:67)
>        at model.Services.SessionEJBDossierBean.getDossierFindAllParDepartementDBTECHandUrgen(SessionEJBDossierBean.java:73)
>        at model.Services.SessionEJBDossierBean.getDossierFindAllParDepartementDBTECHandUrgen(SessionEJBDossierBean.java:73)
>        at model.Services.SessionEJBDossierBean.getDossierFindAllParDepartementDBTECHandUrgen(SessionEJBDossierBean.java:73)
>        at model.Services.SessionEJBDossierBean.getDossierFindAllParDepartementDBTECHandUrgen(SessionEJBDossierBean.java:73)
>        at model.Services.SessionEJBDossierBean.getDossierFindAllParDepartementDBTECHandUrgen(SessionEJBDossierBean.java:73)
>   model.Services.SessionEJBDossierBean.getDossierFindAllParDepartementDBTECHandUrgen(SessionEJBDossierBean.java:73)
>        at model.Services.SessionEJBDossierBean.getDossierFindAllParDepartementDBTECHandUrgen(SessionEJBDossierBean.java:73)
>        at model.Services.SessionEJBDossierBean.getDossierFindAllParDepartementDBTECHandUrgen(SessionEJBDossierBean.java:73)
>        at model.Services.SessionEJBDossierBean.getDossierFindAllParDepartementDBTECHandUrgen(SessionEJBDossierBean.java:73)
>        at model.Services.SessionEJBDossierBean.getDossierFindAllParDepartementDBTECHandUrgen(SessionEJBDossierBean.java:73)

here is my code

```
public List<Dossier> getDossierFindAllParDepartementDBTECHandUrgen() {
    Calendar myFiveDaysAhead;
    myFiveDaysAhead = Calendar.getInstance();
    myFiveDaysAhead.add(Calendar.DATE, 5);

    TypedQuery<Dossier> query;
    query =
        em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Dossier d WHERE d.depid=1 AND d.typeDossier = :tpd AND " +
                       "d.dateCreation < :fiveDaysAhead", Dossier.class);

    query.setParameter("tpd", "Urgent");
    query.setParameter("fiveDaysAhead", myFiveDaysAhead, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
    return getDossierFindAllParDepartementDBTECHandUrgen();
}
```

Comment: You are calling the function `getDossierFindAllParDepartementDBTECHandUrgen()` in itself (i.e. recursively), with no way of stopping that (no terminating condition), hence the StackOverflowError .

Answer (score 2):

you return:

```
 getDossierFindAllParDepartementDBTECHandUrgen()
```

so an infinite recursion is occurred.

your method call the method, which call the method...

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there is no base case for the method to exit, try this

```
public List<Dossier> getDossierFindAllParDepartementDBTECHandUrgen() {

    ...
    return query.getResultList();
}
```